# Is there a listener for when a wear activity is dismissed

Tags: android, wear-os

I need to do something when one particular activity on the wear app is dismissed. Is there any listener for that? I tried with `onBackPressed()` hoping that's the one, but unfortunately not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there is no system support listener for this function, but i can give you another way to do this:
use a listener system to do this, just try

```
// add the listener when you want to catch the event
EventCenter.addListener(ActivityDestoryEvent.ID, this);

// publish the event when your activity onDestroy
onDestroy(){
   ActivityDestoryEvent event = new ActivityDestoryEvent();
   event.activityName = "test";
   EventCenter.publish(event)
}
```

this is a way to implements a event system, and it can do many things in wearable

Comment: Have you found that stated somewhere in the documentation?